# Помогите правильно вывести текст в смарти

Tags: smarty

Имеется код:

```
{%foreach from=$title_reverse item='tit' name='i'%}
{%$tit.name|strip_tags%} {%$allregions[$message.region].name%}
{%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %} / {%/if%}
{%/foreach%}
{%if $regions|@count > 0%}
{%$locale.1019%}
{%foreach from=$regions item='region' name='i'%}
{%$region.name%}{%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %}, {%/if%}
{%/foreach%}
{%/if%}
```

Он выводит текст так:
Название + **Город** / Имя сайта + **Город** + Регион

Как поправить код чтобы выводилось всё также, кроме второй раз "Город"?

Comment: переходите уже на смарти 3, там куда удобнее синтаксис

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При таком коде:

```
        {%foreach from=$title_reverse item='tit' name='i'%}
        {%$tit.name|strip_tags%}
        {%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %} {%$allregions[$message.region].name%} / {%/if%}
        {%/foreach%}
        {%if $regions|@count > 0%}
        {%$locale.1019%}
        {%foreach from=$regions item='region' name='i'%}
        {%$region.name%}{%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %}, {%/if%}
        {%/foreach%}
        {%/if%}
```

Будет вывод теста в таком порядке:
Название + Город / Имя сайта + Регион